# VHDL : How to use a 2d-array in generic port as constant?

Tags: arrays, generics, multidimensional-array, initialization, vhdl

I'm using QuartusII (version 13.0 or 17.0) and I'm trying to use a **2d-array with a *specific type* in my entity's generic port**, so I can instantiate a MEMORY bloc with one of that 2d-array columns.

In codes, it would look like this :

I have 2 packages, the 1st one is to handle the *specific type* (fixed type) in which I have a function that converts INTEGER to a configurable size FIXED_type :

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

-- PACKAGE DECLARATION
package fixed_pkg is
    -- type fixed
    type fixed is array (integer range <>) of std_logic;
    
    -- creating a subtype so "fixed" type is easier to write
    constant INT : positive := 5;
    constant DEC : positive := 5;
    subtype t_fixed is fixed(INT-1 downto -DEC);

    
    -- function to convert INT to FIXED
    function to_fixed (
        val : integer;
        l_size : natural;
        r_size : natural
    ) return fixed;
end package fixed_pkg;



-- PACKAGE BODY
package body fixed_pkg is
    -- function INT to FIXED
    function to_fixed (
        val : integer;
        l_size : natural;
        r_size : natural
    ) return fixed is
        variable result : fixed (l_size-1 downto -r_size);
        variable bit_val : std_logic := '0';
        variable i_left : integer := val;
    begin
        result(-1 downto result'right) := (others => '0');
        if (i_left < 0) then
            bit_val := '1';
            i_left := -(i_left)+1;
        end if;
        for i in 0 to result'left loop
            if (i_left mod 2) = 0 then
                result(i) := bit_val;
            else
                result(i) := not bit_val;
            end if;
            i_left := i_left / 2;
        end loop;
        return result;
    end to_fixed;

end package body fixed_pkg;
```

The other package is to handle the MEMORY bloc. It contains types, one example of a 2d-array and a function to initialize a MEMORY from a 2d-array :

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

library work;
use work.fixed_pkg.all;

-- PACKAGE DECLARATION
package some_pkg is
    -- rom type 
    type t_ROM is array (natural range <>) of t_fixed;
    -- 2d-array type
    type t_2darray is array (natural range <>, natural range <>) of t_fixed;
    -- Example of 2d-array
    constant ex_2darray : t_2darray (0 to 2, 0 to 2)
    := ((to_fixed(0, INT, DEC), to_fixed(1, INT, DEC), to_fixed(2, INT, DEC)),
       (to_fixed(3, INT, DEC), to_fixed(4, INT, DEC), to_fixed(5, INT, DEC)),
       (to_fixed(6, INT, DEC), to_fixed(7, INT, DEC), to_fixed(8, INT, DEC))
         );
    -- function to initialize a ROM bloc
    --    <input> init_2darray : 2d array that contains values
    --    <input> column_index : selected column in init_2darray that will be copied
    --    <input> ROM_size  : Size of the return ROM values
    --    <output> values from the column_index-th of init_2darray
    function init_ROM (
        init_2darray    : t_2darray;
        column_index    : natural;
        ROM_size        : positive
    ) return t_ROM;
    
end package some_pkg;



-- PACKAGE BODY
package body some_pkg is

    function init_ROM (
        init_2darray    : t_2darray; 
        column_index    : natural;
        ROM_size    : positive) return t_ROM is
        -- rom values that will be returned
        variable ROM_val : t_ROM(0 to ROM_size-1) := (others => to_fixed(0, INT, DEC));
    begin 
        -- filling ROM_val with values from the column_index-th  in init_2darray
        for addr in 0 to ROM_size-1 loop
            ROM_val(addr) := init_2darray(addr, column_index);
        end loop;
        return ROM_val;
    end init_ROM;   
    
end package body some_pkg;
```

ANNND finally, here is an exemple of instanciation of a bloc MEMORY(ROM) :

```
LIBRARY IEEE;
USE IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

library work;
use work.some_pkg.all;
use work.fixed_pkg.all;



entity ROM is
    generic(    
        ROM_size        : positive := 3;
        init_2darray    : t_2darray := ex_2darray;
        column_index    : natural := 0
    );
    port(   
        clk         :   in std_logic;
        rdAdd       :   in natural range 0 to ROM_size-1;
        out_data :  out t_fixed
    );
end ROM;


architecture arch of ROM is
    -- ROM instantiation/initialization
    constant ROMbloc : t_ROM(0 to ROM_size-1) := init_ROM(init_2darray, column_index, ROM_size);
begin
    -- READ PROCESS 
    process(clk)
    begin
        if rising_edge(clk) then
            out_data <= ROMbloc(rdAdd);
        end if;
    end process;
    
end arch;
```

**MY PROBLEM :**
In that example of codes I gave, when I try to compile, Quartus throws an "Internal Error". BUT, when I'm using only INTEGER type for the values, I have no problem ...

So I don't really understand what is wrong with my codes... here is the quartus report :
[image]

> screenshot Quartus Error (Quartus 17.0) when "start compilation"

*NB : I'm not using the existing standard fixed package, it's my constraint*

Does anyone know how can I handle this problem ?

Thanks for your help !

Comment: How about trying a newer version of Quartus? 13.0 and 16.0 are 9 and 6 years old

Comment: *... it would look like this*  The package shown isn't syntactically correct as shown (e.g. missing `is array` in array type declarations, ..., incomplete or defective constant declarations, the function declaration has no definition in a package body).  The entity declaration port clause should not be present with no ports.  The code snippet can't duplicate the problem nor allow test of a prospective solution. Provide a [mcve] producing the actual error message. The entity needs a context clause for the package declaration visibility, e.g. `use work.some_pkg.all;`.

Comment: @user16145658 thank you, I understand I'm gonna make it better

Comment: @user16145658 I edited my post, I published a clearer (but longer) example ;)

Comment: Although you are using your own fixed point package, you might want to look at the IEEE fixed point package and the modifications that were necessary to get it working with Altera/Intel.   See:  github.com/FPHDL/fphdl.    Good luck.

Comment: If there are things you find easier in your fixed point package, you might want to suggest changes to the IEEE WG at:  https://gitlab.com/IEEE-P1076/VHDL-Issues/-/issues

Comment: Now that you've completely changed your question invalidating any reader effort to provide an answer previously  (and see [ask])... You're still a bit shy of a [mcve], here lacking any information of what quartus was doing when it received an internal error. What design unit was it working on when it quit? Show any console output. With an added testbench the code simulates correctly, although a column specified as a generic seems to have a limited utility. Tricky's comment may be relevant.

Comment: The [tag:arrays] tag isn't accurately used here. Multidimensional arrays aren't  a linear data structure they are a hierarchy  of linear data structures, See the parentheses in the aggregate providing the value of ex_2darray (it's a shortcoming in the tag definition).

Comment: The added image has little useful information other than you were synthesizing VHDL. Images of text are not useful, the contents don't show up in search (neither do comments). Verific provides HDL parsers (here VHDL) that are used as front ends for tools (here synthesis). This appears to show a problem with the parser. You'd expect to overcome that with a newer version if the problem were known and (eventually) corrected. A search doesn't show a previous reported error with "vhdldeclaration_elab.cpp". You can assume your tool versions are not capable of elaborating your valid VHDL code.

Comment: I'd suspect this has to do with your top level port being of type t_fixed. Consider conversion routines to/from std_logic_vector. It'd likely have something to do with right bound range being negative.

Comment: Hi all, thank you guys for your help, I'm going to keep searching for some solutions and try as you suggest a more recent version of Quartus.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, using 2d-array as parameter in the entity generic port works as long as the value type used in the 2d-array is standard.

So the error from quartus appeared when I'm using my function that converts INTEGER to FIXED type in my 2d-array. I found a way to overcome it and I'm not sure it is appropriate but I succeed to make my design compile without error.

In my package, I just keep my values in my 2d-array as INTEGER type like:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

library work;
use work.fixed_pkg.all;

-- PACKAGE DECLARATION
package some_pkg is
    -- rom type 
    type t_ROM is array (natural range <>) of t_fixed;
    -- 2d-array type
    type t_2darray is array (natural range <>, natural range <>) of INTEGER; -- still integer
    -- Example of 2d-array
    constant ex_2darray : t_2darray (0 to 2, 0 to 2)
    := ((0, 1, 2),
        (3, 4, 5),
        (6, 7, 8)
       );
    -- function to initialize a ROM bloc
    --    <input> init_2darray : 2d array that contains values
    --    <input> column_index : selected column in init_2darray that will be copied
    --    <input> ROM_size  : Size of the return ROM values
    --    <output> values from the column_index-th of init_2darray
    function init_ROM (
        init_2darray    : t_2darray;
        column_index    : natural;
        ROM_size        : positive
    ) return t_ROM;
    
end package some_pkg;
```

Then when I initialize my ROM, I do the conversion to FIXED type through my initialization function:

```
-- PACKAGE BODY
package body some_pkg is

    function init_ROM (
        init_2darray    : t_2darray; 
        column_index    : natural;
        ROM_size    : positive) return t_ROM is
        -- rom values that will be returned
        variable ROM_val : t_ROM(0 to ROM_size-1) := (others => to_fixed(0, INT, DEC));
    begin 
        -- filling ROM_val with *converted* values from the column_index-th  in init_2darray
        for addr in 0 to ROM_size-1 loop
            ROM_val(addr) := to_fixed(init_2darray(addr, column_index), INT, DEC); -- I'M DOING THE CONVERSION HERE
        end loop;
        return ROM_val;
    end init_ROM;   
    
end package body some_pkg;
```

Finally, my goal was to be able to instantiate different ROM components from the 2d-array. In a higher level entity, it would look like:

```
-- [...]
gen_ROM : for i in 0 to 2 generate
    memory : ROM
    generic map (
        ROM_size        : positive := 3;
        init_2darray    : t_2darray := ex_2darray;
        column_index    : natural := i 
    )
    port map (
        clk         => clk,
        rdAdd       => rdAdd_array(i)         -- where rdAdd_array is declared before hand
        out_data    => out_data_array(i)      -- where out_data_array is declared before hand
    );
end generate gen_ROM;
-- [...]
```

where 3 ROM components would be initialized with the columns from the 2d-array.

I hope it will help, just in case someone would face this kind of problem (even if it is specific, I agree).